# Google Hangouts Account Disconnection

Tags: google-hangouts

So I use google hangouts a lot. However, I need it to be disconnected from other devices, such as phones but i can't do it in person. Is there a way I can disconnect it or log out of my account from here?

Comment: On this Site you can ask a question, get an answer but not a service, please read [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help) before writing a question

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with completely signing your google account from your device, you can use http://myaccount.google.com/device-activity. Using this tool you can remove your google account from devices using Google Apps. By removing the google account, you will disconnect Hangouts from your device, but you will also remove GMail,